# Reordering vertex order on a line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, line, vertices

I have made some edits to a cyclepath in ArcGIS. The problem is the order of digitizing of the new vertices is changed and doesn't follows the correct direction, preventing to use it as a GPS track.

Is there a tool for reordering them? It's indifferent if in one direction or the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the "[Flip](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/flipping-lines.htm)" tool on the editor toolbar to flip individual lines, or you can use the "[Flip Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/flip-line.htm)" geoprocessing tool to flip all lines or a selection of lines (select the desired lines or use a definition query on the input layer).